# Swagger-JSdoc is not working on Node.JS 14.15.4 error 'ERR_REQUIRE_ESM'

Tags: javascript, node.js, swagger, swagger-jsdocs

this is not duplicate i have already did researched and checked other stack overflow links such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57169793/error-err-require-esm-how-to-use-es6-modules-in-node-12), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66508616/require-of-es-modules-is-not-supported-error-with-node-js-express-swagge) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61670459/nodejs-must-use-import-to-load-es-module)

I imported swagger in existing Node.JS app like this

```
var swaggerJsdoc = require("swagger-jsdoc"),
var swaggerUi = require("swagger-ui-express");
```

but the error is on swagger-jsdoc the console is following

> internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1080
> throw new ERR_REQUIRE_ESM(filename, parentPath, packageJsonPath);
> ^
>
> Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: Must use import to load ES Module:
> D:\myTestProject\node_modules\swagger-jsdoc\index.js require() of ES
> modules is not supported. require() of
> D:\myTestProject\node_modules\swagger-jsdoc\index.js from
> D:\myTestProject\index.js is an ES module file as it is a .js file
> whose nearest parent package.json contains "type": "module" which
> defines all .js files in that package scope as ES modules. Instead
> rename D:\myTestProject\node_modules\swagger-jsdoc\index.js to end in
> .cjs, change the requiring code to use import(), or remove "type":
> "module" from
> D:\myTestProject\node_modules\swagger-jsdoc\package.json.
>
> ```
> at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1080:13)
> at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
> at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)
> at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:952:19)
> at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:88:18)
> at Object.<anonymous> (D:\myTestProject\index.js:3:16)
> at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)
> at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
> at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
> at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14) {   code: 'ERR_REQUIRE_ESM' }
> ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what I already did is tried the following steps but they did not work

1. Added flag '--experimental-modules' in node starting script
2. `npm install esm --save` //this also did not work

But now finally i found a solution which not requires you to rename your .js files to .mjs also it will not require your node to be upgraded if you are alraedy running Node.Js version 12 or above

simply downgrade your swagger-jsdoc to 6.1.0, which is built with **CommonJS** tools, at first i was using swagger-jsdoc 7.x which was not built using **CommonJS** tools to downgrade the swagger-jsdoc use the following command of npm

```
npm install swagger-jsdoc@6.0.1
```